# When voting an answer down, is it polite to add a comment giving a reason?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, etiquette

When you vote down an answer to a question, do you leave a comment to explain why? Personally I think this is very useful, since if someone has written something that is wrong they can be set straight. Obviously, this may not make sense for highly subjective answers...

Comment: Not only is it polite, it should be downright mandatory if there are not already comments that describe your problem with it (in which case a redundant comment would just be noise).

Answer (score 21):

Yes absolutely. This site is about working together to get the right answers. If someone is incorrect its a great help to let them know why. I hope to get reasons why people vote me down!

Answer (score 9):

If I down-vote something, I always leave a comment as to *why* it's wrong.  Otherwise, people might not learn.  Also, and I feel more importantly, if something is +5 and -3, no one will know it has been down-voted unless there are comments explaining why.

Answer (score 7):

I think a comment should be the first method to show someone you don't agree.  Maybe they can clarify something that would change your mind.  Then downvote if they still don't satisfy you.  A downvote without a comment is almost as unhelpful as a posting that should be downvoted.

Plus, I think questions like this (about SO) should be community wikis, so the rep earned and burned is based mainly on programming knowledge.

Comment: Much as I like this idea - realistically, most of us will view most questions once and then move on. Definitely comment ... and follow this suggestion when you can (e.g. on question in which you are personally interested)

Answer (score 5):

Generally I will only make a comment when downvoting if that comment is actionable.

If an answer is inane or appears to be intentionally unhelpful, or just beside the point, I won't bother leaving a comment. At some point I'd just get tired of writing "don't be an ass", "don't be rude", "don't be an idiot" comments.

If an answer appears to be intended to be helpful but has some flaw, I will be more likely to add a comment. The answerer may have misinterpreted the question, or they may have made some error in coding, or they may not be aware of the deficiencies of their design, so a comment is worthwhile because it gives them feedback and it gives others who read the answer useful information (on whether to use that answer, for example) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes please.  I've gotten a couple of downvotes that I'm still a little confused by, and I'd have loved a few words of explanation (I'm not saying the downvote was unjustified, I just didn't know why it happened.)  And both Questions and Answers, please.

Comment: Frankly, some people just like to wreck a good thing.  For example, on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo , someone came along and marked every single answer down, even though they were all correct.

Comment: Yeah, I've been hit with one or two of those myself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please comment. Sometimes I see a down vote and I don't understand the reason for it. Is the answer technically wrong? Is it off-topic? Is the voter trying to suppress points of view that they don't agree with?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with leaving comments explaining downvotes is that the downvoted person may decide to take revenge and use up his allocation downvoting your contributions.

I'm happy with the anonymity factor to be honest.

Sure if I get a down vote I'll leave a comment under my answer or question asking the reason why, but if I don't get one I'm not all that bothered, and nor should I be. After all it's only a website (albeit a fine one), it's not like my credit rating is being affected. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a step further and suggest that it's polite to comment *any* vote.  As others have said, the purpose of StackOverflow is to share information.  IMHO, constructive comments—whether or not you agree with them—are always helpful.  Personally, I find I learn most from the folks who *disagree* with me.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote ... where's the comment!?  :-)

Comment: Totally agree +1

Comment: +1 agreed. "+1 agreed" would be enough but is not accepted as a comment..

Answer (score 1):

I'd say maybe. If there's a good reason to vote down, like technically wrong, or not answering the question, or flawed, then yes. We all learn from it. If they respond with something like "VB is teh suck!", then I think it goes without saying.

Comment: I do not understand. "VB is teh suck!" is technically correct. ;)

Comment: VB RULEZ!!111!!!1!!!one!!11

Comment: Actually, to be technically correct, it should be "VB is teh suX0rs!"

Answer (score 1):

I think explanation on downvote of question and answer is always useful, though should **not** be compulsary.

Without it people often won't see why unaided, for themselves, why the downvote was cast.

Answer (score -1):

Down votes on questions, not necessarily.  Down votes on answers, usually.

Answer (score -1):

You should **always** leave a comment on a downvote, because the person receiving the downvote has the right to know why. If somebody leaves an answer which he or she believes is helpful, then gets a downvote without an explanation, that person will be left wondering why the answer got downvoted. There may be rare exceptions, but it doesn't take any time to leave a comment such as "Not at all helpful" to somebody saying gibberish or something like "VB is teh suck!". I believe that it should be required to leave a (potentially anonymous) comment with a downvote.

Comment: You may want to add that on uservoice. I think however, that the overhead of commenting would keep people from downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Yes- I was recently downmodded on an answer which I presume to be absolutely correct.   If it is not, I would gladly delete the comment and learn something from it.  Otherwise I am left doubting my own answer.

I am also afraid that some people may see the highest ranked answer and take that one to be 'correct' while others are 'incorrect'.  My answer was not upmodded so it was not deemed correct or incorrect, but then another answer that had an opposing answer was upmodded.  It clearly made my answer appear incorrect.

If anyone reading this may have been responsible, here is the post I am concerned about: 
[Singleton Destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273720/singleton-destructors#273799)

Answer (score -2):

certainly not perfect, but just to give an idea on a potential automatic rule that may be "social" friendly
something like ...

**votecount < 0 and Upvote and no existing comment** :
 >>***invite*** user to add a comment 
**votecount <0 and upvote and (existing two or more comments) or one comment get 2+Up** :
 >>***do not invite*** to add comment  
**votecount = 0 and Upvote and no existing comment** :
 >>***invite*** user to add a comment  
**votecount > 0 and Upvote and existing comment** :
 >>***do not invite*** to add a comment 
 
**votecount = 0 and downvote and no existing comment** :
 >>***Oblige*** user to add a comment 
**votecount > 1 and downvote and no existing comment** :
 >>***Oblige*** user to add a comment 
**votecount > 1 and downvote and with existing comment** :
 >>***Invite*** user to add a comment 
**votecount > 5 and downvote and with not comment** :
 >>***Oblige*** user to add a comment